# create a view to cater to dynamic month

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

a subquery is provided to create a view and the view should cater to dynamic month variable.

the subquery like this:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4, sum(money) as KPI_single_month from table1 group by col1,col2,col3,col4 where month='202104'
```

-- month is not fixed, maybe 202103,202106

the view should be called like this:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,KPI from view1 where month='202104'
```

--month is not fixed, maybe 202103,maybe 202106

the key output of this view is KPI, which is the sum of KPI_single_month from 202101 to 202104.
if month is 202106, then sum(KPI_single_month) from January to June(total 6 months).

so the difficulty of creating view is that the month variable is unknown, how many subquery should I sum in the SQL statement of creating view?  Thanks!

Comment: This should be handled in your reporting front end tool(s).  You could do it in a stored proc, but (at least in my opinion) it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: You might try to add `month` to the group by. Of course, you should check if the optimizer is capable of pushing the condition iinto the select *before* aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Why are trying to create a view instead of a stored procedure to get the required sum
You pass the month to the procedure and it create a temp table then query it or just ouput the sum

Comment: in my production environment,  Stored Procedure need to be reviewed with restricted measures while view need not.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not possible to pass parameters to the view (not sure about Teradata specific)

Comment: I agree with you. My goal is not passing parameter to the view.

Comment: anyone know if Teradata support passing parameter to view?  In Oracle database, there is a feature of syscontext which can pass parameter to view.

Comment: In Teradata, views do not allow parameters. Macros and Stored Procedures allow parameters and can return answer sets - but cannot be used in a FROM clause. Table Functions / Table Operators (C/C++ or Java code) can potentially accept parameters and return result sets that can be processed by an outer query but that's significantly more complex.